# How can I setup users/groups in PostgreSQL so that each user has privileges on objects created by other users in the same group?

Tags: postgresql, users, access-control, postgresql-11

I have created a group (role) called "employees" and I've created some users that are its member and that inherit its rights. I have a database owned by the group "employees".

The goal: To setup things in a way that allows all of the users to work with all of the objects in the database.

The problem: I can't expect the users to set the owner to "employees" when they create a new object, because they use various limited interfaces to work with the database. When they create a schema or a table, it gets created with the user as its owner, which means that the other users don't have rights on that schema/table.

I'm using PostgreSQL 11.2.

Comment: Maybe it is enough to work with default permissions on a schema?

Comment: You cannot do it if you limit yourself to tools that do not allow the users to perform a simple statement like `SET ROLE employees`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have

```
GRANT employees TO john;
```

Just do

```
ALTER USER john SET ROLE TO employees;
```

Now when `john` connects he will automatically have role `employees` and when he creates an object it will be owned by `employees`;